# Migrating fonts stack from SCSS to JSS (cssinjs)

Tags: css, fonts, material-ui, jss, css-in-js

We're utilizing a lot of custom fonts with varying weights for various purposes. Now that our whole stack is using Material UI with JSS theming and styling, we'd like to get rid of the last few `.scss` files in our folder architecture.

All of the fonts are working perfectly with the SCSS syntax as of now.

We have an `index.scss` file imported in the main entry point of the app. It has a single line in it:

```
@import 'styles/fonts';
```

`styles/_fonts.scss` contains a lot of font faces:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FooFont';
    src: url('styles/fonts/FooFont_LtIt.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And the `styles/fonts` folder has all of the font files in it.

I have already succeeded in attaching global Material UI `makeStyles` styling to the `head`. This allows me to inject global CSS instead of component-based JSS:

```
'@global': {
    '@font-face': [
      {
        fontFamily: 'FooFont',
        src: 'url("styles/fonts/FooFont_Rg.ttf") format("truetype")',
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontStyle: 'normal',
      }
    ],
    '*': {
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
    },
    html: {
      height: '100%',
    },
...
```

This syntax adds a `<style>` tag at the bottom of the `<head>` and applies the styles. This works for non-font styling.

**The main issue with this:** For some reason, it doesn't update my font stack. The fonts are downloaded, but the page elements still use the fallback font.

I have also tried using JSS directly and injecting the CSS at the top of the `<head>`. No luck. Writing fonts manually into the `<style>` tags at the top of the head downloads the font (I can see them appearing in the Network tab) but the page elements update and still use the fallback font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add the fonts in an inline style tag in your `index.html`?

That way they will load right away and be available to your other code.

I use CSS in JS a lot but always load fonts in my root index file.

So just do this in your *index.html*

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'FooFont';
    src: url('styles/fonts/FooFont_LtIt.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Then you can manage all your other styles whatever way you want

Comment: As stated in my post, I use a lot of fonts, so this would most certainly grow my index.html by a lot. That would make the file rather hard to maintain. I'd like to manage all styles in one place, and that is my styles folder which contains all styles, including fonts.

Comment: You can separate concerns if you want by using a standard CSS file and importing that instead.

The issue is trying to specify your font paths via CSS in JS which may perhaps work, however in my experience hasn't been worth the headache for me.

If you inject it to the head, the DOM has already been loaded by the time the font is available

Comment: Yes, this is most likely the issue. I'll bring it up with the team on Monday.

Comment: Cool! You can improve on it. But it's Friday, and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be runnning into this issue https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/908

Comment: Well, I don't see any errors in the console. I might have to reproduce the problem in codesandbox. If it really is a bug, I could raise it to the css-in-js team or material-ui.

Comment: And the fonts do get inserted into the `<head>`, the issue is that apparently the font-family cannot find my font.

Comment: Maybe I'm lacking some basic css knowledge here, but the confusing part is that the scss syntax and the inserted css are pretty much the same.